# iOS change CSS of external Site

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, proxy

I'm new to iOS programming and i want to make a simple app thad displays some websites.

But the Websites are not optimized for mobile use and I can't change anything on the original server.

I tought thad the simpelst way would be to change the css from this site to fit my needs.

Is it possible to change the CSS of a site in the webview or so.

Or do i have to make a Proxyserver thad changes everything and connect to it.

Thanks
Greeting from Switzerland
Brian

Comment: Duplicate :: this could answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536338/changing-css-on-the-fly-in-a-uiwebview-on-iphone